# custom exception message not displaying in the console

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have this simple program demonstrating exception handling in .NET, i am catching the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in this case, but the custom message that i pass to the console is not getting displayed.

```
using System;

class program
{
static void Main()
{
    int[] source = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] destination = { 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    try
    {
        Array.Copy(source, destination, 7);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, there is something wrong in the program ! : {0}", e.Message);
    }
}
}
```

and here is the output screenshot

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're catching `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, but the method is throwing an `ArgumentException`.
Therefore, your `catch` block never executes.

Comment: I didnt notice that. Thanks a lot for the help ! Much Appreciated.